# GCP Big Query scheduled query UTC to local time zone bug

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have scheduled my queries to run at 11:50pm local time, however Big Query runs them an hour early.

**Is this a known issue?**

I have scheduled them to run at 12:50am the next day but I am worried this will cause more issues.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was a daylight savings issue and I needed to change the date to the current day before changing the time.
Not very intuitive.

[image]